# подключить папку в JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

есть папка models, controllers, routes. В данных папках есть JS файлы примерно такого вида:

```
module.exports = user = {

  add: function(firstName, lastName){
    console.log(firstName, lastName)
  },
  update: function(user){
    console.log(user)
  }
};
```

как подключить все файлы одним разом? допустим

```
var models = require("/models");
var controllers = require("/controllers");
var routes = require("/routes");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Определить в папках **index.js** файлы, в которых подключить все файлы.

К примеру, если в папке **controllers** есть модуль **testcontroller.js**, создайте в папке **controllers** файл **index.js** с таким содержанием:

```
module.exports.testcontroller = require('./testcontroller');
```

Теперь, если вы где-то подключаете папку **controllers**:

```
var controllers = require("/controllers");
```

Вы сможете обратиться и к **testcontroller**:

```
controllers.testcontroller.вызвать_какой_то_метод()
```

Или прогнать все файлы в папке и подключить. Например, папку **controllers**:

```
var normalizedPath = require("path").join(__dirname, "controllers");

require("fs").readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
  require("./controllers/" + file);
});
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев рад помочь ^_^